# Pre-Populate foreign keys in SQL with a new row

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

I am trying to write a SQL script which will go through a table with a newly created FK and pre-populate the key with a new row in the foreign table. I'm not 100% on how to do this or if its even possible in a single statement but here's my attempt:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Blogs]
set AuthorSecurableId = inserted.Id
FROM  [dbo].[Blogs] updating
INNER JOIN 
    (INSERT INTO [dbo].[Securables] (Name) 
     OUTPUT Inserted.id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Inserted.Id) as rownum
        SELECT 'Admin : ' + Name
        FROM Blogs
        WHERE AuthorSecurableId is null) inserted ON ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY updating.Id) = inserted.rownum 
WHERE updating.AuthorSecurableId is null
```

When I do this I get the following error

> Msg 10727, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed on either side of a JOIN or APPLY operator.

Below is a simple view of the schema I have

[image]

I would like to create a securable for each blog which doesn't have one and populate that blogs `AuthorSecurableId` with the `ID` of the newly created securable

I think I could do this with a cursor but I was wondering if there is a better single statement approach

Comment: Wow, that's a crazy complex thing to do in a single query.  Why not build a stored procedure that opens a cursor (select * where null), loops through it, inserts new securetable, gets @@identity, and updates the blog record?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @StevenMoseley yeah maybe i should just bite the bullet and use a cursor. I dont want to make this a SP as I actually only want to do it once, the whole point is to update the DB and then make the column non-nullable

Comment: @gbn needs to be able to run on SQL 2012 and SQL azure

Comment: You can't do an `INSERT` and an `UPDATE` in one statement. You have to do them in 2 statements.

Comment: WHY do you want to do it in a single statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use merge against `Securables` with output to a table variable or temp table and a separate update against `Blogs`.

```
declare @T table
(
  SecID int,
  BlogID int
);

merge Securables T
using (
      select 'Admin : '+B.Name as Name, B.Id
      from Blogs as B
      where B.AuthorSecurabledId is null
      ) as S
on 0 = 1
when not matched by target then
  insert (Name) values (S.Name)
output inserted.Id, S.Id
  into @T;

update Blogs
set AuthorSecurabledId = T.SecID
from @T as T
where Blogs.Id = t.BlogID;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e2984/2)

Comment: Thanks, this method definitely works. I am doing this in an EF database migration method so I prefer to avoid temp tables and cursors, but it seems this is the easiest way